# Flex order not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `nav` element with 3 child divs, with widths 25%, 50%, and 25% respectively, also flexbox order 1,2 and 3 respectively. In mobile view, I want to shift the second element down to next row taking full-width and first and third to stay in the first row consuming 50% widths each. I changed the second element's order to 3 and width 100%, also third element's order to 2 and 50% width. However, it is still not working as expected. Is it possible to achieve something like that using flexbox?

I have included a sample code

```
<nav>
  <div class="a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    C
  </div>
</nav>
```

and CSS

```
nav{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.a,.b,.c{
  border:1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
.a{
  width:25%;
  order:1;
}
.b{
  width:50%;
  order:2;
}
.c{
  width:25%;
  order:3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){

  .a{
    width:50%;
  }
  .b{
    width:100%;
    order:3;
  }
  .c{
    width:50%;
    order:2;
  }
}
```

or use the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anoopdecodes/szu544mz/6/)

basically this is what I'm trying to achieve.

default view
[image]

on mobile
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s9v926g9/1/

There are 2 things you need to add:

**Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the nav element**

This will make the elements wrap to a next line, instead of spacing themselves out over the available width.

**Set the box sizing**

Adding

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to your css will make sure the borders are not messing up your flex-wrap.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was very similar to my implementation.

Comment: `flex-wrap` has nothing to do with `order`.

Comment: @Neurotransmitter `flex-wrap: wrap;` will make sure that on the mobile layout the nav elements are spaced over multiple lines. 

the order is used to shift the order of the nav elements in the mobile layout.

They are not closely related, but both needed for the situation described in the question.

Comment: @JasperZelf I just removed `flex-flow: wrap;` from your example (https://jsfiddle.net/s9v926g9/1/) and the order still works as expected. `A`, then `C`, then `B`. `flex-wrap` is for wrapping, and the `order` is for ordering.

Comment: @Neurotransmitter Yes... wrap is for wrapping. And that's exactly what needs to happen on the < 400px wide view. The question has 2 images, the 2nd is how it should be on <400px wide. a and c next to each other, b on the bottom, wrapped to the next 'line'.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `flex-wrap: wrap` on flex container and then you can just change order on mobile size and set `flex: 0 0 100%` on `b` element. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/szu544mz/11/)

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.a, .b, .c {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
.a, .c {
  flex: 1;
}
.b {
  flex: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .b {
    order: 2;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</nav>
```